# invalid_payload while sending Json data from a file to slack using web hooks

Tags: json, http, curl, webhooks, slack

I'm using this command

```
payload=$(jq '.' /home/test/package.json)
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "$payload" URL
```

but i get invalid_payload and/or no_text error

i tried using the cat command as well like this

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data "$(cat package.json)" URL
```

but still the same error

the json format looks like this

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "t",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "p",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
    "bn.js": "^5.2.1",
  }
}
```

Comment: I would use a proxy like Fiddler to pickup what you are actually sending over the wire. I am guessing you are either escaping the JSON or its wrapped the entire thing in a set of quotes and rendering it invalid from slacks viewpoint.